# How to avoid a postback in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page which has a button it it. The button click launches a modal dialog box using JavaScript. Based on the value returned by the modal dialog box, I want to proceed with, or cancel the post back that happens. How do I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding "return false;" to the onclick attribute of the button will prevent the automatic postback.

Comment: If any exceptions are thrown before the return false, the automatic postback will still occur.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Click!" />

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    var agree = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if (!agree) return false;
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function HandleClick()
{
 // do some work;

if (some condition) return true; //proceed
else return false; //cancel;
}
```

set the OnClientClick attribute to "return HandleClick()"

Answer (score -1):

Basically what Wayne said, but you just need to put 'return false;' in the function that presents the modal. If it's the value you want, let the postback happen. If not, have the function return false and it will stop the submit.